# XML numbers of results by attribute name

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am using the following XML file

```
     <OnThisDate date="2013-02-22">
      <event jobnumber="14434" allocated="1" name="ADI UK ">
        <i1001 driverID="30" driverName="None None" groupname="i100"/>
        <i251 driverID="0" driverName="" groupname="i25"/>
        <i252 driverID="0" driverName="" groupname="i25"/>
      </event>

      <event jobnumber="14559" allocated="1" name="Travel">
        <i1006 driverID="46" driverName="Martin Macklin" groupname="i100"/>
      </event>

      <event jobnumber="14560" allocated="1" name="Travel">
        <i1005 driverID="0" driverName="" groupname="i100"/>
      </event>

      <event jobnumber="14690" allocated="1" name="Travel">
        <i253 driverID="0" driverName="" groupname="i25"/>
      </event>

      <event jobnumber="14695" allocated="1" name="Holiday">
        <i602 driverID="10" driverName="Alan Linney " groupname="i60"/>
      </event>

      <event jobnumber="13595" allocated="1" name="Sandown Park Racecourse">
        <i1002 driverID="6" driverName="Simon Latcham" groupname="i100"/>
      </event>

      <event jobnumber="14447" allocated="1" name="Sandown Racecourse">
        <i125 driverID="35" driverName="Carl Boxall" groupname="i12"/>
      </event>

      <event jobnumber="14030" allocated="1" name="Warwick Racecourse">
         <i601 driverID="5" driverName="Tom Robson" groupname="i60"/>
      </event>
     </OnThisDate>
```

The nodes under each event have a **groupname** attribute and I want to get total results by group name , so in the example the sum of groupname i25 would be 3

I have been able to get the sum of the children of event using this code

```
var count=$(data).find('event').children().size();
console.log(count)
```

But I cannot work out how to get the rest of it to work

Any help please ? , thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a count of all elements with a specific group name:

```
var groupname = "i25";
var count = $(data).find('*[groupname="' + groupname + '"]').length;
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FW7ad/)

Side note: `.size()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. The use of `.length` is recommended instead.